# Can I advertise in Google AdWords with multiple places to click in an ad with different actions?

Tags: advertising, google-ads

I want to create a graphical Ad for my website that has more than one button or a multiple choice question.   It possible to run such an ad in the Google AdWords content network?

If so, how do I set it up, and how can I tell which button or action the user selected in the ad?

I thought that Google's "rich media" ads might be able to do it.  I have searched the [Rich Media Gallery](http://www.richmediagallery.com/gallery/) that they provide and haven't found examples of ads with multilple click points.

Comment: The only Google ads I've ever seen with multiple click points are the Product ads that will show multiple products in one ad. And those are auto-populated by Google Remarketing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just took ages to find, I persevered because I was sure it was possible...

It is possible, and can be seen with some animated ads being served on the Google network.

In addition to multiple click destinations in an animated ad, it is worth reviewing what [is and isn't allowed with animated display advertising on the Google network](https://support.google.com/adwordspolicy/answer/176108?hl=en-GB), specifically the following which could be used in conjuction with multiple clickable areas within an ad:-

- Ads can simulate mouse or computer actions like mimicking the movement of a mouse icon within the parameters of the ad, as long as the mousing effects stop after 5 seconds.
- Ads can have mock animated features or icons as long as the functionality works or the purpose of these features can be achieved on the landing page.

Google also [explain what image types formats and sizes are allowed](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722096?topic=7052) on their network.

Google uses the `clickTAG` parameter (within ads built using Flash) to identify click through's to multiple URL's in one ad and supports multiple instances of this so that multiple URL destinations can be used - you can read about this [here and instructions are as follows](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1656701?hl=en):-

> To create a Flash creative with multiple clickTAGs:
>
> - [Add a new custom creative](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/177229).
> - Upload the Flash SWF file and backup image to the custom creative.
> - Enter a creative name and click-through URL. Select the target ad unit
>     size.
> - Copy and paste the code snippet found below.
> - Modify the dccreativewidth and dccreativeheight lines to be the
>     correct ad unit size for the creative.
> - If the backup image was not a .jpg, change %%FILE:JPG1%% to the
>     appropriate file server macro. ([Learn more about macros](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1242718))
> - Click Save.
>
> If you'll be uploading more Flash creatives with multiple click-through URLs, you can save time by making a creative template that you can reuse over and over again. ([Learn how to create custom creative templates](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1138308))

The page also includes a code snippet example.

Here is a [useful tutorial](http://www.flashclicktag.com/) on working with `clickTAG`'s in Flash.

And [getClickTAG](http://getclicktag.com/get-clicktag-code/) also offers code snippets for Actionscript 2.0 and Actionscript 3.0 along with downloadable sample Flash (.swf) files.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Good detective work.  I think you are saying that it is only possible with flash ads and not with image ads or html5 ads?

Comment: You can use the `clickTAG` parameter in Flash or HTML5 ([like so](http://test.adform.com/testpage/banner-specifications/html5-banner/)). I don't think you can in any other format though.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question.  With only one clickTag, how is it possible to have multiple urls in a single ad unit.

Comment: @JohnC - You can't with only one clickTag, you have to add multiple within the ad.

Comment: As far as I can tell, adwords only supports one clickTag, hence I don't think this is possible.